Data Cloud: How to ingest binary files (PDF, Word, etc.) from Salesforce CRM (ContentVersion)?
I'm trying to get my unstructured data from Salesforce CRM (Sales + Srv Cloud) into Data Cloud. In particular I want to ingest PDF, Word, Excel, etc. files to then be able to use them with an Agentforce Agent.
I am referring to files stored as ContentDocument/ContentVersion.
However I am only to connect external data sources like Amazon S3, not CRM. Also the CRM connector won't allow me to do this.
I do not have Mulesoft available.
Can anybody point me into the right direction?
Thanks!

Data Cloud now supports Knowledge Article Attachments as of October. General Salesforce Files are not yet supported (Nov '24)
